# Table representation using css

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Consider the scenario like this.

I have Array List of string arrays.

I want to represent them in the image shown below.
[image]

currently I have implemented this as Table. But this is not dynamic. Going forward I have to loop twice which seems some what difficult.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Pack1</td>
    <td>Ch1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>ch2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Pack2</td>
    <td>val1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>val2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Please let me know any other approach using css styles.

1. Loop through every pack
2. Again loop through each pack to get the values.

Comment: What do you mean by “but this is not dynamic”?

Comment: @icktoofay.Each pack has different values. So, in the first column I have to give the name of the pack and in the second column I have to give the name of values in it. All the values are being fetched from java code in JSF. SO I thought implementing in a generic way separating packs with its values.

Comment: Still working on this?

Answer (score 1):

This will likely be a little bit of a hot-potato as it's not entirely clear what you want exactly though I've posted a bit of a more structured table format that seems to resemble your goal. If you know how to use `colspan` and `rowspan` then you can adjust the table (e.g. if you want multiple rows on a single column) though consider how tables are intended and mostly style by default. I've added some CSS and text to help give you an idea of how (X)HTML tables work when you take advantage of things.

As far as looping I think you can apply the idea of "packages" to `tbody` elements that are like partitions of a table...they're part of the same kind of data though have their own separate groups.

Comment if you need help adjusting this, it's not difficult.

```
<table summary="Describe your table here." style="border: 1px solid #aaa; border-collapse: collapse; width: 40%;">

<thead style="background-color: #f77;">
<tr><td colspan="3">Table Header</td></tr>
</thead>

<tfoot style="background-color: #f77;">
<tr><td colspan="3">Table Footer</td></tr>
</tfoot>


<tbody>
<tr style="background-color: #fcc;"><th colspan="3">Pack 1 (Tbody Header)</th></tr>
<tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>
<tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>
<tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>
</tbody>


<tbody>
<tr style="background-color: #fcc;"><th colspan="3">Pack 2 (Tbody Header)</th></tr>
<tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>
<tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>
<tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```